# Path finding with multiple levels

Tags: algorithm, game-engine, path-finding, a-star, multi-level

I'm dabbling in some path-finding systems (right now A*), but I'm no where near experienced enough to fully grasp the concepts behind everything. So please forgive me if this post is riddled with ignorance, or false assumptions.

My goal is to be able to have an object traverse multiple planes to reach a destination, with variable entrances to each level, and each level having different designs.
imagine a cave system that has 8 entrances on top, and your goal is to reach 6 layers down... Some of the caves link up, and therefor paths can be shared, but others are isolated until a certain point.... etc etc. Also, the inter connectivity of paths can be altered on each level.
I know there are some systems that can do this, but my goal is eventually best/fastest option, as well as the ability to do this calculation quickly (a possibility of at least 80+ different paths being calculated at any given time)

An example would be something like this:
[image: Layered/Planes pathing]

Every 'layer' is another 'level', or plane. The green is a path that is both up and down between layers. during the course of the instance, paths can be placed anywhere, and any divisions inside a layer can be removed (but for the case of this instance, they are organized like that)

Its been fairly easy to implement A* for some basic path finding on a single level (eg, get from one position to a ladder going down). But trying to decide which ladder will lead to the ultimate goal is what is difficult.

My initial thoughts were to do something more like a data structure linking the paths to each other on the same level, and do some sort of tree traversal to decide which ladder the the path finding should direct you to when you reach a certain level...but that got complicated quickly, seeing as levels can be altered at any given point.

Like i said, I'm not certain how A* actually works, or the basics behind it... but its the basic algorithm that most people have said will work for multi-layered designs.

I know that it really depends on the engine, and the implementation of the algorithm, so I'm not asking for specifics... but rather some pointers on the best way to approach the situation;
Should I find a working A* implementation that has multi-level calculations built in, and change my level architecture to fit it?
Should I simply utilize a 2d A* implementation, and create a 'path' structure, to give the pathing instructions on each level?

Is there another approach to this style of design that would be more beneficial, and efficient (taking into account the number of calculations/paths to find)?

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is, A* can do this just fine, but you need to actually understand what it's doing in a graph-theoretical sense.

Comment: A\* is an algorithm that works on graphs.  Modeling your problem as a graph should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that comes to mind:

For each level, calculate all the [Manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) (perhaps `/2` if you can move diagonally) (that's assuming each level is a 2D grid) from each ladder going up to each ladder going down, and let each floor's value be the shortest distance of those.

Now we can simply let the A* heuristic be the sum of distances from the current floor to the bottom.

---

To prevent repeated computation of paths on each level, we can precompute each possible path from ladder to ladder on every level - we can also then use the shortest of these paths rather than the Manhattan distances for the heuristic.

---

You say there is a possibility of at least 80+ different paths being calculated at any given time.

If these are all on the same map, you should consider, for each ladder, calculating what the next ladder we should go to is which will lead to the shortest path (and also its cost) (possibly using some derivative of [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) starting from the bottom), then we can simply, from any starting point, check the distances to all ladders on the same floor and the cost of their shortest path, and simply pick the one giving the lowest sum of distance and shortest path.

We could even extend this by storing, for any given point, what the next square is one should move to for the shortest path.

If the map changes a lot, storing the next point for any given point is probably not viable, but don't discount storing the next ladder for each ladder.

Comment: I have thought about having each ladder list what ladders they can reach (up and down, in case you have to go up again, before you go down--as shown in that picture). That 'value' for each ladder would be updated whenever the 'structure' of the surrounding levels change (thus possibly changing the viable path between 2 ladders on that level).

I assumed the best option would be Dijkstra's from the bottom, flagging all the 'available' ladders on the origin level, and choosing the closest 'flagged' ladder. That way, you are literally only path finding to the closest flagged ladder on each level.